# Map differing length variables to one data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, join

Suppose I have to following data

```
specialty <- c("Primary Care", "Internal Medicine Subspecialties" , 
 "Pediatric subspecialties","Surgical subspecialties", "Emergency 
  Medicine","All other specialties", "No Medical specialty")


 test <- c(23,43,67,77,54)

dfTEST <- data.frame(test)
dfTEST<- t(dfTEST)
colnames(dfTEST) <- c(1,2,4,5,7)

> dfTEST
      1  2  4  5  7
 test 23 43 67 77 54
```

Note that my dfTest has 5 variables that skip numbers. I need to create a data frame that maps these colname numbers (1,2,4,5,7) to the specialty. Specialty is 7 strings that are in coordination to the dfTest colnames. Meaning dfTest 2 = "Internal Medicine Subspecialties" and dfTest 4 ="surgical subspecialties and so on. Below is a snippet of what I am looking to achieve, but I am stumped on how to go about it. I need it to be flexible so that no matter what the numbers in the colnames are, the code will still work. Any ideas?? Thanks!!

```
> dfTEST
          1                2           4  5  7
 test     23              43           67 77 54
added "primary care"   "internal" ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
# get the indexes of correspondent specialties
ids <- as.integer(colnames(dfTEST))
dfTEST<- as.data.frame(t(dfTEST))
dfTEST$added <- specialty[ids]
dfTEST<- t(dfTEST)
```

The output:

```
> dfTEST
      1              2                                  4                        
test  "23"           "43"                               "67"                     
added "Primary Care" "Internal Medicine Subspecialties" "Surgical subspecialties"
      5                                     7                     
test  "77"                                  "54"                  
added "Emergency \n               Medicine" "No Medical specialty"
```

Answer (score 2):

This here should solve your problem.

```
library(dplyr)
specialty_lookup <- data.frame(specialty = c("Primary Care",
                         "Internal Medicine Subspecialties", 
                         "Pediatric subspecialties",
                         "Surgical subspecialties",
                         "Emergency Medicine",
                         "All other specialties",
                         "No Medical specialty"),
           test = 1:7, 
           stringsAsFactors = F)

data  <-  data.frame(code = c(23,43,67,77,54),
                  test = c(1,2,4,5,7))

data <- data %>% 
  left_join(specialty_lookup)

data_wide <- data %>% 
  select(-test) %>%
  t() %>% 
  data.frame()

colnames(data_wide) <- data$test
data_wide
```

But you should question yourself if this is really the format you want your data to have. From the little I could see of your problem, the following format would be more adequate:

```
library(dplyr)
specialty_lookup <- data.frame(specialty = c("Primary Care",
                         "Internal Medicine Subspecialties", 
                         "Pediatric subspecialties",
                         "Surgical subspecialties",
                         "Emergency Medicine",
                         "All other specialties",
                         "No Medical specialty"),
           test = 1:7, stringsAsFactors = F)

data  <-  data.frame(code = c(23,43,67,77,54),
                  test = c(1,2,4,5,7))

data <- data %>% 
  left_join(specialty_lookup)

data
```